# Why is SaveInstanceState implemented differently in a Fragment( vs an Activity)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-savedstate

For example, in an `Activity` the method is protected:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
```

whereas in a `Fragment` it’s public:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle currentState) {
```

I’ve seen it in several apps so far. Why is that? Thank you.
Please note that this is a general question, not related to any specific code/app.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` is an Android-lifecycled component managed by the system. `Activity#saveInstanceState()` is called by `Activity#performSaveInstanceState()` that is eventually called by system `ActivityThread`. Since it's in the same class hierarchy, `protected` is enough.

`Fragment` lifecycle is managed in a different way by `FragmentActivity` with the help of other related classes. State saving is performed via `FragmentManager#saveAllState()`. Since it's in another class hierarchy, `Fragment#onSaveInstanceState()` needs to be `public` so that it can be called.

To learn about things like this it often helps to read the platform source. For example, I often resort to [androidxref.com](http://androidxref.com/) to quickly browse around platform source code.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation and the link.